# Gentile owning a tallit

Tags: halacha, gentiles, tallit-katan

I am a Gentile. In my naïvete I bought a tallit katan a couple of years ago. I did not know the halakha regarding these things at the time. I very soon realised that I should not wear it, and it has been lying in a cupboard since then. I thought about it again today, and wondered whether I might be cursed on account of simply owning it. Is there any law against a Gentile owning a tallit, if he does not wear it / use it?

P.S. I kept it because I was, and still am, intending to convert.

Comment: I'm not aware of any issue with a gentile owning a tallit, or maybe even wearing it. No need to be nervous.

Comment: I am not aware of any laws that forbid a gentile to own it (as there's nothing such among the 7 Noahide laws), but I know about one that forbids a Jew to sell it to gentiles.

Comment: I have never seen any prohibition of a Gentile owning an object used in performing a mitzvah, still less any curse assocaited with it. This question https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43797/can-a-noahide-wear-a-tallit-without-the-tzitzit-fringes-during-their-personal-pr?rq=1 deals with wearing it - see there.

Comment: @Kazi - Ok, thanks - I will hand it over to my LOR then, so the Jewish company who sold it to me is not held to account. Blessings, T

Comment: @TomW Why don't you give it to someone who may use it (by asking help from this rabbi), so with your help he will merit to do a mitzvah? I don't think you've done anything wrong, on the contrary, by donating you'll do something good!

Comment: @Kazi - thank you - yes, I will try to give it to someone who can use it. Blessings

Comment: It's a long, sometimes hard road to conversion, @Tom, why don't you hold on to the tallit katan to remind you where you're headed?

Comment: @Josh - thanks, I may do that :)

Comment: I am also not aware of any curse for owning things, or generally curses. This is not really a Jewish concept. Congrats on your efforts and may you success in your spiritual endeavors

Comment: @mbloch - thank you, with blessings